# Android location updates

Tags: android, gps, location, android-wifi, locationmanager

I am trying to make an accurate location based app but I am a little bit confused on how the [requestlocationupdates](/questions/tagged/requestlocationupdates) works.

1. If I put the `requestlocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, , );` as a location provider and I test my app. I see that if I haven't enabled the gps it takes updates from the network and when its enabled it takes it from the gps. What is the point of setting both network and gps providers to send updates if they switch on their own?
2. How does the third parameter of `requestlocationUpdates` work? I mean it says that it changes in the distance that I set but how it can detects that I have moved?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following code

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

where Criteria is a class indicating the application criteria for selecting a location provider. Providers maybe ordered according to accuracy, power usage, ability to report altitude, speed, and bearing, and monetary cost.

then

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,0, 0, new MyLocationListener());
```

Where second and third parameter are use to so that you can control the frequency at which your listener receives updates with the second and third parameter—the second is the minimum time interval between notifications and the third is the minimum change in distance between notifications—setting both to zero requests location notifications as frequently as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the response but my question is that the code that you wrote me i put it in the onResume method, so if the best provider for my criteria is the gps but it is unavailable how the app will choose network provider on its own and change when the gps is available. Do i have to check this on my own? As for the second one my question is how can it detect that i have moved more than my mindistance parameter?This means that it counts all the meters?

Comment: as per your first question locationManager.getBestProvider will provide you best provider i.e either gps or network. You dont have to do anything.

Comment: Yes but if i the system chooses gps for example but it becomes unavailable will it change to network on its own?

Comment: ya..but if you use locationManager.getBestProvider

Answer (score 0):

1. keep in mind, once you requestLocationUpdates(...) means onLocationChanged(...) will be triggered when provider specified is enabled and you will get the latest coordinate in onLocationChanged method. There is a default location aka Cache location, or LastKnownLocation which that system will be use before detecting any new location.
2. Of course system will treated that you're moving when your current location is different than your previous location (cache location).